# Who wins this hand?-rules

Tags: rules

Who wins this hand ?

Player 1 - king 2 off suit 
Player 2 - ace 9 off suit

Flop- 2,3,6
Turn-5.         (Flop,turn,river all off suit )
River-4

Comment: as the op is talking about a specific hand I don't think this counts as a duplicate, although the reference made by Paparazzi would help this player understand the rules of Poker better.

Comment: @lukefranklin, it's the same question. The hands may be different, but the rules for determining the winning hand are the same.

Comment: I agree the rules are the rules and it could be seen as a duplicate but I think given it's a specific hand it could be original.

Comment: @LukeFranklin Many people feel questions like this clutter the site and show no research.

Comment: thanks @Paparazzi, I will leave my answer for the OP but join the rest of the community in answering/helping where research is available.

Answer (score 0):

it is a split pot.

the reason being poker is played to 5 cards, on the board, there is a straight 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

even if player 1 has KK and player 2 has AA it is split pot as a straight is a higher ranking hand than a pair.